# How do I add Xft suppport to dwm?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, fonts, dwm

I would like to use the [inconsolata font](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) in [dwm's](http://dwm.suckless.org/) statusbar. Right now my config.h is set up like so using terminus:

```
static const char font[] = "-*-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*";
```

I tried changing that to:

```
static const char font[] = "-*-inconsolata-medium-r-normal-*-17-*-*-*-*-*-*-*";
```

But it didn't work. I currently have inconsolata working in urxvt by setting the following line in .Xdefaults:

```
URxvt.font: xft:inconsolata:size=10
```

So, I believe the best bet would be to just patch Xft support into dwm, but I can't seem to find a patch anywhere and I'm not sure how to do it myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently using dwm 5.8.2.

*(At the time of this writing I didn't have enough points to create new tags so I just went with X11 and fonts, please feel free to modify).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a (reasonably old) thread on the [suckless mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/dwm@suckless.org/msg05639.html) about this issue, that includes a patch: called [pango](http://www.mail-archive.com/dwm@suckless.org/msg05666.html).

There is slightly more recent version in the AUR for 5.8.2:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=33193

Comment: if I download the package from the AUR and then modify config.h and run makepkg, I get an error that config.h didn't pass the validity test and won't install.

Comment: I didn't realize you were running Arch. Download the tarball, extract and cd in. Then run `makepkg`. Once the package is built, edit config.h and then `makepg -efi`.

Comment: You have to edit the PKGBUILD and remove anything between md5sums=().You can also do makepkg -g >> PKGBUILD but then the PKGBUILD will get cluttered.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I suppose I should have mentioned that I am using Arch... thanks for your answers, worked like a charm.